# Crystal Reports formula to create new field data based on specific condition?

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

I am relatively new to Crystal Reports (I have version 2013) so I understand how some things work, but I cannot figure this issue out.

My database source for the report is secure and cannot be changed, so I have to make the change in crystal reports. Basically I have a field called Jurisdiction that has a set number of possible entries. I need to create a new entry in the Jurisdiction field if a certain city is within the CITY field. Here is what I am thinking for code, but I cannot get it right:

```
if {database.CITY}='SPRINGFIELD' then {database.JURISDICTION}='SPRINGFIELD' 

else {database.JURISDICTION}=defaultattribute
```

I know that the defaultattribute does not work here, but I do not know what to use. I have also tried the code without the else statement which does not give me any errors, but on the report it displays "False". Also can I create just a regular formula to drag onto the report or should it be created within the Section expert in the details section?

Comment: what is your default attribute value?

Comment: u can try this 
 if {database.CITY}='SPRINGFIELD' then 'SPRINGFIELD' 

else ''

Comment: I was under the impression that the default attribute would be the original data that was already in the record. Therefore if {database.CITY} was NOT 'SPRINGFIELD' then {database.JURISDICTION} would remain unchanged with its original data value.

Comment: I do not see how this:if {database.CITY}='SPRINGFIELD' then 'SPRINGFIELD' else '' is going to change the value in the {database.JURISDICTION} field.